# How I can use columnDefs and buttons in the dataTables?

Tags: datatables

I want to remove sorting from all columns in the table and want to add a `Print` button on top.

But when I am using below code the print button is missing:

```
$('#printData').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "paging": false,
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    buttons: [{             
            extend: 'print', footer: true,
            title:'<div style="text-align:center;">Test Report</div>'
        }],
    columnDefs: [{   
        "visible": true,
        "searchable": true
    }],         
});
```

Anyone can let me know can we use `columnDefs` with `buttons`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want print button on top and also some other button in table column?

Comment: No, I want to remove the sorting and search field from top and show only the print button.